# Where can I find the code for Arduino's "attachInterrupt"?

Tags: programming, interrupt

Where can I find the code for [Arduino's `attachInterrupt`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) function?

A search on the [Arduino's Github repo](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino) yielded nothing.

I suspect it might be a wrapper for some avr-libc function but nothing in [the avr-libc docs](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) stands out to me...

Comment: download a text editor like `Notepad++`  ..... you can then use it to search for text in folders (directories) ..... search for the text "attachInterrupt" in the arduino install directory .... it will find all files that contain that word   ..... get it here https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the core in WInterrupts.c

On my install it's at:

arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c

Comment: Thank you! Never knew I could find these files in the install!

Comment: How could you compile them if they weren't there?

Comment: Online: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c